# Rights Clearance for Self-Publishers

Tags: copyright, non-fiction

Asking a lawyer to vet a book would be very expensive. Someone told me a better option is to hire a firm that specializes in reviewing books for intellectual problems, publicity rights, defamation, etc.

After doing a little research, it sounds like the term is **rights clearance**, or **media clearance**. Although there's a lot of information online, I've had a surprisingly hard time 1) learning the basics and 2) tracking down a company to hire.

I finally found one firm that specializes in copyright issues only, with a $250 initial consultation.

Can anyone point me to a reference that explains this process, hopefully with some information on price range and links to some companies that work with self-publishers? (I write non-fiction, by the way.)